# Cannot install Volley in Android using build.grandle

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Android. Now I am learning Android Volley HTTP library. But when I install using build.grandle, it added Java class to the libs folder. But it is throwing error and cannot run the project.

I added compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' to grandle file.

This is my grandle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

So I tried to update by running the app. It installed the required files. But when it is about to start it is showing this error and app is not running.

This is the screenshot

[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: Your picture is saying that you are using Java 8 to build the android app. You can only use Java 7 to build android app.

Comment: So how can I fix this error ?

Comment: In Android Studio, click `File`, then `Project Structure`, then specify the location of your Java SE 7 installation, if you don't have one, download the latest Java 7 version.

Comment: I clean removed all the code using volley and cleaned project. Then run the project again. It is working now. Wth is wrong with it?

Comment: Last time, I used volley.jar, it is throwing error. Then I closed and open the android studio again. Error gone away. So silly

Comment: Yeah, sometimes when you make a change to your code, and it won't compile, just clean and rebuild your project, it is as easy as clicking a button. No complaint needed

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

in your grade add

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 23

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    ..... // other stuff 
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

more info please that

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I don't think its the error related to volley. Make sure you have an active internet connection and  your Xml  file is free from errors.